# how to get radio value from radio button by form api drupal

Tags: forms

How to get radio value from radio button by using the following code

```
$form['pd']= array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#title' => t('Programme Day'),
  '#options' => array(0 => 'One Day Programme', 1 => 'Two or More Day Programmes'),
  '#required'=>TRUE
);

$form['one_day'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Date'),
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#description' => t('Please select the date of Programme'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#date_format' => "d-m-Y h:i A",
  '#date_year_range' => -15:+1',
  '#states' => array('visible' => array(':input[name="pd"]' => array('value' => 0)))
);


$form['from_day'] = array(
  '#title' => t('From Date'),
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#description' => t('Please select the from date of Programme'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#date_format' => "d-m-Y h:i A",
  '#date_year_range' => '-15:+1',
  '#states'=>array('visible'=>array(':input[name="pd"]'=>array('value'=>1)))
);

$form['two_day'] = array(
  '#title' => t('To Date'),
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#description' => t('Please select the To date of Programme'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#date_format' => "d-m-Y h:i A",
  '#date_year_range' => '-15:+1',
  '#states'=>array('visible'=>array(':input[name="pd"]'=>array('value'=>1)))
);
```

I tried the following code but the value shows as array not value.

```
$prog_day = $form_state['values']['pd'];

$one_date = $form_state['values']['one_day'];
$from_date = $form_state['values']['from_day'];
$two_date = $form_state['values']['two_day'];
```

Comment: Are you sure the 'pd' #type must be 'radio'?
Try 'radios'

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6#radios

Comment: its not working its display the error msg "Array"

Comment: try this $prog_day = $form_state['values']['pd'][0];

Comment: Thanking you sir its working. but i cant get it  $two_date = $form_state['values']['two_day'];    date field value

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for the submitted values you need to look in the `$form_state` and not the `$form array`.

use `$form_state['values']['your field name']`, 
depending on element type you might have `['und'][0]` or just `[0]` on the end.

Comment: Any idea how to get the textual value related to the selected index within `_form_submit` ?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal collects the submitted values of form in the $form_state array by default so you will get the radio button value in following variable:

```
$form_state['values']['pd']
```

Answer (score -1):

you need a default_value to get the value !

```
$form['pd']= array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#title' => t('Programme Day'),
  '#options' => array(0 => 'One Day Programme', 1 => 'Two or More Day Programmes'),
  '#required'=>TRUE,
  '#default_value' => 0,
);
```